# Automate the workflow between user input in webpage UI and GitHub Codespaces VScode terminal

Tags: python, github, automation, github-api, codespaces

There is a CLI tool(https://www.npmjs.com/package/mcdev/v/3.0.0) which I use regularly and it is a very useful tool. This tool is only available as  CLI and does not have any UI . So far I was using it on the VScode desktop and my team members were not able to access the file (as it was on my local computer).

Recently I discovered Github Codespaces VScode (browser based). With this it was possible for team members to access and run commands remotely. But since many of my team members are non technical they want to use the tool though the UI and not commands. They want me to automate the workflow.
For example when user inputs a value in the UI, this value should trigger a command in Github Codespaces VScode (browser based).

I tried exploring different options to do this and came across a few ideas and was not sure which way to go. I am not an expert developer and new to this.  Here are some of the solutions which I have in mind,

1. **Using python**
   User inputs the value in the webpage UI and the value should be passed to the python script. The python script then creates a command with the value passed from the UI  and then opens the url of the VScode browser version. Next the same python script runs a command in the VScode terminal.
2. **Using Github codespaces API**
   My first preference is to use the REST API. I was not able to locate an API that I can call from my webpage UI to run a command in VSCode codespaces (browser based). Does anyone know if i am missing something and this can be done through an API?

Could you please let me know which solution would be the most appropriate to use here? As I am new to development and also this needs to be implemented  fast due to the deadlines I want to pick easy and quick solutions. Also any other quick and easy solution other than the ones i mentioned would be helpful.

Comment: This question may be hard if not impossible to answer without at least a little context. What CLI tool are you talking about? If it's not just internal to your company, chances are that somebody on SO has experience with it.

Comment: the tool is called Accenture dev tool - https://www.npmjs.com/package/mcdev/v/3.0.0